# SSL Verification Issues with SharePoint API

Tags: python, ssl, sharepoint, openssl, pyopenssl

I am trying to upload files directly to a SharePoint site using the REST API, but am experiencing issues with SSL. In my search for answers, most reported issues are with the `requests` package, and I am unable to locate a solution specific to SharePoint. I found a similar post in which the solution was upgrading pyOpenSSL, so I tried that with no change in the error message.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code and error messages as text and not as a barely readable screenshot. Also, this specific error about failed certificate validation is very common and there are lots of similar posts here. The error might be caused by server side misconfiguration or by client side problems like not having the right certificate authorities in the local trust store. Too much unknown here since nothing is reproducible.

Comment: Looks like you might have a self-signed cert at the endpoint.  Either find a way to ignore certification validation in your code, or install the self-signed cert on all clients where your REST API script will run, or install a proper certificate at the endpoint signed by a Trusted Root CA.